# Multi Device Hybrid App - Ripple using old Cordova version

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2013, ripple, multi-device-hybrid-apps

We are in the process of switching our development from Redgates VSNomad to Microsoft Multi Device Hybrid App and I've run into a problem using he Ripple emulator.

It seems Ripple can only use Cordova 3.0. Part of our app uses navigator.globalization.dateToString which fails with 'Cannot read property 'dateToString' of undefined'

I'm reasonably sure this is because navigator.globalizationation was added in a later version of Cordova. Is there any way of getting ripple to use a later version?

The Ripple emulator we used with the Nomad project does support navigator.globalization

UPDATE: I've also found that navigator.camera is undefined when running in Ripple so maybe the problem is not related to Cordova version. (navigator does have a value)

Comment: They recently committed support for 3.6 according to https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=incubator-ripple.git;a=commit;h=1dcc5cdc75f811abd9c35fc7ea852d408dadc272. Should work when you build it yourself, I'm not sure which version of Ripple you are using.

Comment: I'm not specifying a Ripple version - as far as I know, I can't. Visual Studio starts it up when debugging is started.

Comment: So you are using [this extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn757052.aspx)? I guess it is up to Microsoft to update the bundled Ripple version. Are you using the latest [v0.2 from 9/16/2014](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42675) of the plugin?

Comment: You should be able to use both of those plugins in Ripple with the CTP2.0.  Have you opened config.xml and selected those plugins in the Plugins tab?  You need to do that in order for them to be installed and available for use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for the plugins to be installed and available for use in your application you need to open config.xml and select them in the plugins tab.  Once you do that and rebuild, both those plugins should work fine in Ripple.